# Identifying the model LangChain is using

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, langchain, huggingface, py-langchain

I am currently struggling with the following issue. I have set a pipeline to use LLaMa-2 using HuggingFaces, with the following code:

```
from torch import cuda, bfloat16
import transformers
from langchain import HuggingFacePipeline
from langchain import PromptTemplate,  LLMChain
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory


model = transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        'meta-llama/Llama-2-70b-chat-hf',
        cache_dir='/my/cache/dir',
        trust_remote_code=True,
        config=model_config,
        quantization_config=bnb_config,
        device_map='auto',
        use_auth_token=hf_auth
    )

pipe = transformers.pipeline(
    model=model, 
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    return_full_text=True,  # langchain expects the full text
    task='text-generation',
    stopping_criteria=stopping_criteria,  # without this model rambles during chat
    temperature=0.01,  # 'randomness' of outputs, 0.0 is the min and 1.0 the max
    max_new_tokens=480,  # mex number of tokens to generate in the output
    repetition_penalty=1.1  # without this output begins repeating
)

llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline = pipe, model_kwargs = {'temperature':0})
```

After that, I initialize the langchain with some custom memory and prompt parameters:

```
llm_chain_0 = LLMChain(
    llm=llm,
    prompt=prompt,
    verbose=True,
    memory=memory_0)
```

The problem is that, if I try to retrieve details on my langchain using the `llm_chain_0` command, this is what I get:

`LLMChain(memory=ConversationBufferMemory(chat_memory=ChatMessageHistory(messages=[HumanMessage(content='This is the user's question, ignore', additional_kwargs={}, example=False), AIMessage(content="  This is the model's answer", additional_kwargs={}, example=False)]), output_key=None, input_key=None, return_messages=False, human_prefix='Human', ai_prefix='AI', memory_key='chat_history'), callbacks=None, callback_manager=None, verbose=True, tags=None, metadata=None, prompt=PromptTemplate(input_variables=['chat_history', 'user_input'], output_parser=None, partial_variables={}, template='[INST]<<SYS>>\nYou are a helpful assistant, you always only answer for the assistant then you stop. Read the chat history to get context\n<</SYS>>\n\n\nChat History:\n{chat_history} \nUser: {user_input}[/INST]', template_format='f-string', validate_template=True), llm=HuggingFacePipeline(cache=None, verbose=False, callbacks=None, callback_manager=None, tags=None, metadata=None, pipeline=<transformers.pipelines.text_generation.TextGenerationPipeline object at 0x2ac4e8da6290>, model_id='gpt2', model_kwargs={'temperature': 0}, pipeline_kwargs=None), output_key='text', output_parser=StrOutputParser(), return_final_only=True, llm_kwargs={})`

As you can see, the `model_id` appears to be `gpt2` and not LLaMa-2. I am just wondering if I am doing something wrong and thus don't have the right model loaded.

Thank you all in advance for your patience and for any help you can provide.

Comment: did you tried querying multiple questions to llms, how the result look like..

Comment: @ZKS I am not sure what you mean by that. You mean asking multiple questions? Because the answers mostly seem fine, but I am also asking very basic stuff. I wouldn't know how to make sure just by asking questions to the LLM alone.

Comment: Did you change the sequence? I am seeing `pipe` get used before initialization.

Comment: @PranjalDoshi Sorry about that! I fixed it.